# C# generating a dynamic list of buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic

So I'm trying to generate a dynamic list of buttons in a WPF in C#, but I'm finding it to be very difficult. No matter how I try to do it, I get the error that 'Button' does not contain a definition for ''(in this case Text and Dock, and then that I can't convert the button in the Controls.Add(b) line. I don't really understand what's going on but no solutions I've found on StackOverflow have solved this yet so I felt I should ask someone to explain what's going wrong here.
Thanks for anyone who takes the time to help out!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App_Manager
{
    public partial class GroupListScreen : Window
    {
        SQLiteManager SQLMan;
        public GroupListScreen(SQLiteManager SQLman)
        {
        SQLMan = SQLman;
        GenerateList();
        InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GenerateList()
        {
            TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1 = new TableLayoutPanel();
            List<QueryData> listGenerate = SQLMan.getData();
            var rowCount = listGenerate.Count/3;
            var columnCount = 3;

            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = columnCount;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = rowCount;

            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear();
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
            {
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100 / columnCount));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
            {
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100 / rowCount));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount * columnCount; i++)
            {
                System.Windows.Controls.Button b = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
                b.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
                b.Name = string.Format("b_{0}", i + 1);
                b.Click += b_Click;
                b.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put `InitializeComponent()` mathod before `GenerateList()`

Comment: WPF is not Winforms. If you want to write Winforms code, you should use Winforms. If you want to use WPF, you need to learn WPF idioms. The above task is best addressed by using data templates, not generating elements in code. If you must generate elements in code, you need to understand that `Button` has `Content` property, not `Text`, `TableLayoutPanel` is a Winforms object, and you really shouldn't be trying to use it in WPF anyway.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you for the input, this stuff came up even though I googled 'wpf' and I'm not very experienced with these things so I didn't really understand.

Comment: @BadJukeBox - There should be tons of questions relating to doing this. It's one of the most over-asked questions here.

Answer (score 0):

You should get started with MVVM when using WPF.
It's a very easy task for generating dynamic lists. Short summary: An ObservableCollection and an e.g. ListView in your View with an ItemsTemplate and that's it. No code behind needed ;)